# MongoDB get distinct elements from array WITH count of occurrences of each element

Tags: mongodb, group-by, aggregation-framework

I have the following documents in my collection. Each document contains the text of a tweet and an array of entities picked out of the tweet (with AWS Comprehend):

```
{
"text" : "some tweet by John Smith in New York about Stack Overflow",
"entities" : [
    {
        "Type" : "ORGANIZATION",
        "Text" : "stack overflow"
    },
    {
        "Type" : "LOCATION",
        "Text" : "new york"
    },
    {
        "Type" : "PERSON",
        "Text" : "john smith"
    }
  ]
},
{
    "text" : "another tweet by John Smith but this one from California and about Google",
    "entities" : [
    {
        "Type" : "ORGANIZATION",
        "Text" : "google"
    },
    {
        "Type" : "LOCATION",
        "Text" : "california"
    },
    {
        "Type" : "PERSON",
        "Text" : "john smith"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to get a list of distinct `entities.Text`, grouped by `entities.Type` WITH a count of the occurrences of each `entities.Text` like so:

```
{ "_id" : "ORGANIZATION", "values" : [ {text:"stack overflow",count:1},{text:"google",count:1} ] }
{ "_id" : "LOCATION", "values" : [ {text:"new york",count:1},{text:"california",count:1} ] }
{ "_id" : "PERSON", "values" : [ {text:"john smith",count:2} ] }
```

I've can group by `entities.Type` and put ALL the `entities.Text` into an array with this query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $unwind: '$entities'
}, 
{
    $group: {
        _id: '$entities.Type',
        values: {
            $push: '$entities.Text'
    }
}
}])
```

which results in this output that includes duplicate values and no count.

```
{ "_id" : "ORGANIZATION", "values" : [ "stack overflow", "google" ] }
{ "_id" : "LOCATION", "values" : [ "new york", "california" ] }
{ "_id" : "PERSON", "values" : [ "john smith", "john smith" ] }
```

I began going down the path of using `$project` as the last step of the aggregation and adding a calculated field `valuesMap` with a javascript function. But then I realized that you cannot write javascript in the aggregation pipeline.

My next step will be to process the mongoDB output using plain javascript but I was hoping (for learnings sake) to get this all done using a mongoDB query.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use `addToSet` instead of `$push` to add distinct elements into array. check the answer below.

Comment: @RahulRaj sorry, should've mentioned, I did try that. That will give me distinct elements but... then I'll lose the ability to get a count for the **occurrences of each element**.

Comment: Alright got you now, deleting my answer as the answer made by Veeram is right one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try below query. You need an extra `$group` to push the count and text.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
  {"$unwind":"$entities"},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{"type":"$entities.Type","text":"$entities.Text"},
    "count":{"$sum":1}
  }},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$_id.type",
    "values":{"$push":{"text":"$_id.text","count":"$count"}}
  }}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: '$entities'
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    Text: '$entities.Text'
                },
                count: {
                    $sum: 1
                },
                Type: {
                    $addToSet: '$entities.Type'
                }
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    Type: '$Type'
                },
                values: {
                    $addToSet: {
                        text: '$_id.Text',
                        count: '$count'
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        // Stage 4
        {
            $project: {
                values: 1,
                _id: {
                    $arrayElemAt: ['$_id.Type', 0]
                }
            }
        }

    ]


);
```